# How to make the time stamp difference for inserting and updating record in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, c#-4.0, mongodb-.net-driver

I need to create a time stamp in my mongodb collection. Am using C# in front end .My code is :

```
        internal static void CreateStudent(string Id, string Name,string strUserId)
        {
            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(ConnectionString);
            MongoDatabase mydb = server.GetDatabase("Database");

            MongoCollection<BsonDocument> Student = mydb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Student");
            BsonDocument colectionGenre = new BsonDocument {
                       { "Code", Id }, //Id is Auto Generated in sql. Fetch from there using Output parameter and save it in one variable and pass that here 
                       { "Name", Name },
                       { "Status","Y"},
                   {"stamps" , new  BsonDocument { 
                        {"Ins_date", DateTime.Now}, 
                        {"up_date",""}, 
                        {"createUsr", strUserId}, 
                        {"updUsr", ""},
                        {"Ins_Ip", GetIP()}, 
                        {"Upd_IP",""}}}
                       };
            Student.Insert(colectionGenre);
        }

        internal static void UpdateStudent(string Id, string Name,string strUserId)
        {
            MongoServer server = MongoServer.Create(ConnectionString);
            MongoDatabase mydb = server.GetDatabase("Database");

            MongoCollection<BsonDocument>Student = mydb.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Student"); ;
            // Query for fetch the ID which is edited by the User...(user can only able to edit the NAME field alone)
            var query = new QueryDocument {
                  { "Code", Id }};
            // After Fetch the correspondent ID it updates the name with the Edited one
            var update = new UpdateDocument {
                  { "$set", new BsonDocument("Name", Name) }
                          };
           // Updated Query.(Id is same as previous. Name is updated with new one)
           {"stamps" , new  BsonDocument { 

                        {"up_date",DateTime.Now},
                        {"updUsr", strUserId},
                        {"Upd_IP",GetIp()}}}
                      }}
      };
        Student.Update(query,update,UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True);
    }
```

It works fine for INSERT method with time(Stamp) once the record is created. But the problem is with update method. When user update something the insert time also changed with the updated time..

After User Updates the Name, i want my will collection looks like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5178aea4e6d8e401e8e51dc0"),
"Code": 12,
"Name": Sname,
"Stamps:"{
"Ins_date":03:34:00,
"up_date": 04:35:12
}
}
```

But my problem is both the time will same after update. That is because it takes the current date and time function..How can i achieve the above output.It needs any driver.Suggest something for me...

Comment: Why are you setting the insert date value when you say you don't want it to be changed? Update merges with the existing doc, and doesn't replace.

Comment: are you using the upsert flag?  I don't see it in the code but it sounds like you don't know whether the record will be updated or inserted?

Comment: @AsyaKamsky I tried with the like this (Upset flag UpdateFlags.Upsert, SafeMode.True)..But it is remains same.

Comment: So is the issue that on insert you want insert time to be set but on update you don't?

Comment: see my answer. you need to use $set for up_date but $setOnInsert for Ins_date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally  I got answer...In INSERT method Simply pass the below things

```
  {"Insert-stamps" , new  BsonDocument { 
      {"Ins_date", DateTime.Now}, 
      {"createUsr", strUserId}, 
      {"Ins_Ip", GetIP()}}},
   {"Update-stamps" , new  BsonDocument {
       {"up_date",""}, 
       {"updUsr", ""}, 
       {"Upd_IP",""}}}
```

And In UPDATE method

```
 {"Update-stamps" , new  BsonDocument { 
       {"up_date", DateTime.Now}, 
       {"updUsr", StrUserId},
       {"Upd_IP",GetIP()}}}
```

It works Fine for my standard....

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a value for the `Ins_date` field when you're updating the document. Just remove that from the update document and it won't change it.

```
var update = new UpdateDocument {
     {"$set", new BsonDocument { 
        {"State_strName", name}, 
        {"stamps" , new  BsonDocument {
          {"up_date",DateTime.Now}, 
          {"createUsr", ""}, 
          {"updUsr", ""},
          {"Ins_Ip", GetIP()}, 
          {"Upd_IP",GetIP()}}}              
       };
    tblmytbl.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: When i remove insert field means that insert time i cannot get there.. only update time will bwe there.. i need both the time

Comment: @Aarthi don't remove the insert time field.Just change ur updated time  while updating.

Comment: I pass this code based on condition. when user id="401" it checks condition if the value is not present means it goes to insert statement. so i make the up_date," " for first time. If the value 401 is present it goes to update part..

Comment: do you mean you use the "upsert" option true?  I don't see that in your code.

Comment: @sachin hi.. how to change that updates time without removing Insert date

Comment: @matthewtole:if i remove that Ins_date while update it is all so removing that field from collection... plz guide some code.....

Answer (score 0):

How you are updating the value in the existing document by using unique id or other unique value.Check whether the unique id or value is already exist in your database documents.If it is exist means change the update time only don't do anything..

Comment: this answer is same as @matthewtole answer.But i think that this will help you to understand the previous answer.

Comment: I pass this code based on condition. when user id="401" it checks condition if the value is not present means it goes to insert statement. so i make the up_date," " for first time. If the value 401 is present it goes to update part. So when updat part executes means im unable to get the inserrt time here..

Comment: @Aarthi When ur update part will execute if u have already inserted the document.So no problem.

Answer (score 0):

While updating the data in mongoDB,you are passing the same values for Ins_date and up_date i.e. DateTime.Now(current system date and time).So the same values are updating in your monoDB document.

For this you can do one thing :-
Before updating your mongoDB document you take Ins_date values from your database by using sql query in C#.net and then use this value for Ins_date and for up_date use DateTime.Now then your both values will be different.

```
var update = new UpdateDocument {
         {"$set", new BsonDocument { 
            {"State_strName", name}, 
            {"stamps" , new  BsonDocument {
              {"Ins_date", **Ins_date values_from your database**} ,  
              {"up_date",DateTime.Now}, 
              {"createUsr", ""}, 
              {"updUsr", ""},
              {"Ins_Ip", GetIP()}, 
              {"Upd_IP",GetIP()}}}              
           };
        tblmytbl.Update(query, update);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need is the new [$setOnInsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/setOnInsert/) operator which was added in 2.4 for exactly this use case.

When the update with upsert flag results in an insert, you want to $set insert_date to Date.now but when it's a regular update, you don't want to set it at all.  So now with your update you should use `$set` for regular fields you want to set whether it's an update or an insert, but use `$setOnInsert` for fields that should only be set during insert.

Comment: @ Asya Kamshy I cant able to set the mention flag in my code.. it throws error

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What flag? What error?  $setOnInsert is not a flag, it's an operator, like $set